# Contents of nested structure emptied when passing it through a socket

Tags: c, sockets, structure, unions

I have this structure:

```
enum msg_type {CONN, CRESP, INT, STRING};
typedef struct gen_msg {
    enum msg_type type;
    union {
        connection conn;
        connection_response cresp;
        int i;
        char s[256];
    };
} gen_msg;
```

The `connection` structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct connection {
    char name[BUFLEN];
} connection;
```

I know I could just replace the structure in my `union` by a simple `char[]`, but since the information I send when connecting may someday contain something more than the name, I prefer to keep it in a structure.

The first structure, `gen_msg`, is used to pass messages between a client and a server through sockets. In my client, I have this:

```
printf("Please enter your name: ");

if (fgets(ibuf, BUFLEN, stdin) != NULL) {
    ibuf[strlen(ibuf) - 1] = '\0';

    gen_msg msg;
    msg.type = CONN;
    strcpy(msg.conn.name, ibuf);
    printf("Name to be sent: %s", msg.conn.name);
    write(server, &msg, sizeof(msg));
}
```

The `printf` prints the name correctly. Now, on the server side, I do this:

```
gen_msg receive_msg(int client) {
    int nbytes;
    gen_msg msg;

    if ((nbytes = recv(client, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0)) <= 0) {
        if (nbytes == 0) {
            /* Server connection closed */
            fprintf(stderr, "The client closed the connection\n");
            close(client);
            FD_CLR(client, &master_fdset);
        } else {
            perror("error - recv");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return msg;
}

int main() {
    /* Other stuff to initialize the server, handle the clients, etc. */

    while(1) {
        gen_msg msg = receive_msg(client);

        /* Do some checks and storage */
        /* The following just copies the players' name inside a structure     that contains information regarding the connected players */
        strcpy(g_info.players_tab[g_info.num_players].name, msg.conn.name);

        fprintf(stderr, "Accepted player %s\n", msg.conn.name);

        /* More other stuff */    
    }


}
```

This prints `Accepted player`, so it doesn't get the name. However, when I use my `gen_msg` to transmit other things, like an `int` or a `char[]`, it works perfectly. I tried this with a single client connected, so it couldn't be the wrong client. Please note the structure is sent between a client and a server that runs on a single machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think anyone can solve your problem without all the code.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you mean that it seems to be OK like this and so you think some code could've modified the contents of `msg.conn.name` outside of what I showed here?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I could of course be wrong. :-)

Comment: You should check the return values of `write()` and `recv` (which are the number of bytes written/received). Both may be less than the size of your buffer because the data has been written/read only partially.

Comment: I updated my code to add the only line that does anything with `msg.conn.name`. Going to check the return values.

Comment: It isn't a matter of "the only line that does anything with msg.conn.name". Any line in your program could be causing the problem if it is causing "undefined behavior". Make copies of your code and prune it down to the smallest example that demonstrates the problem and post that.

Comment: `printf("nbytes: %d, size: %ld\n", nbytes, sizeof(gen_msg));` outputs `nbytes: 188, size: 268`, so there's indeed something off. Yet, sometime later when the first player sends the maximum score, it outputs `nbytes: 268, size: 268`. Both send messages using the same exact structure and the same `write` instruction.

Comment: Additionally, if you're testing sending this structure between machines of differing architectures and/or compilers the structure layout may have been altered.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. I noticed I forgot to remove a `recv` instruction when I refactored my code, which is obviously what caused the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PLPeeters: If the first recv() reads only 188 bytes then the next recv() will read the remaining 80 bytes from the first message first. So even if recv() returns 268 later, you are "out of sync". - Both on the writing and on the receiving side you have to loop until the complete message has been sent/received.

Comment: It may be embarrassing, but it's also normal, so don't be too embarrassed! Did you discover that when you were creating your minimal example? Sometimes a different perspective like that is all you need.

Comment: I did indeed discover that during the creation of my MWE. Other question: how go I got about this SO post now, so I don't leave an unresolved question behind? Should I post what caused it as an answer and accept it or should I just delete it?